# How to set the default selection in list items on the blackberry screen

Tags: user-interface, blackberry

I have added a list of items in my blckberry screen using custom list field class. i am able to display list of items on my bb screen, but how to set the default selection as first item in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [setSelectedIndex(int index)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ListField.html#setSelectedIndex%28int%29) in API Documentation.

Example:

```java
ListField list = new ListField();

// do other task, add on screen

list .setSelectedIndex(3);
```